# Can't see beyond a certain point in viewport?

Tags: 3d-view

[image: Cube, shown cut off]

For some reason I can't seem to see things in my viewport beyond a certain point, as if there is an invisible wall. For reference, the photo shows a cube, but I am unable to see the rest of it. If I drag my perspective around, the line at which the objects stop showing remains constant. Please help!

Comment: Thank you so much, I didn't realize that the clipping distance was the issue :)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you might need to increase the *Camera End Clip Distance*. Press N in the viewport, and select the "View" tab on the right side of the menu that appears. Clip distance is near the top. See below:

[image: Clip]